# How to overwrite ngModel input styling

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

In my Ionic app I use `[(ngModel)]` to bind and pass input value in my class.

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" floating>flow [m <sup>3</sup> /h]</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="flow" (change)="calculate()"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

The problem is that it applies styling for my input that I don't want to. For example green border at bottom as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGpWY.png)

So I tried to overwrite it in `scss` file:

```
page-fan-choice {
    .ng-valid * {
        border-bottom-color: #dedede;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

but it didn't help. I check the console and I saw that default styling is higher in the hierarchy tree than mine. See below:

```
.item-md.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner {
    border-bottom-color: #32db64;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #32db64;
}
page-fan-choice .ng-valid * {
    border-bottom-color: #dedede;
    box-shadow: none;
```

I also tried to use `!important`. I helped but it also overwrited default ionic styling for input that I want to keep, for example blue bottom border when you click it. So the bottom border was remaining grey `(#dedede)` all the time.

---

**How can I overwrite this ngModel styling without modifying default Ionic styling?**

Comment: can you create a plunker for it?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360804/how-to-remove-default-color-in-input-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the CSS rule that you're having a hard time overriding :

.item-md.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner {}

And let's say the div you're trying to style has another class 'foo', to set it apart.  Just change that rule to add the extra class in your component.  Now it's more specific.

```
.foo.item-md.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make the specificity of your style higher than the one you want to override.

```
div#test span { color: green }
div span { color: blue }
span { color: red }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity