# How to disable form-validation in Ionic 3 and Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation, ionic3

The forms in Ionic Framework 3 with Angular 4 validates `<ion-input/>` and `<ion-textareas/>` automatically. As soon as I blur the input field, it gets validated and the border color changes (*in my case*) to green.

```
  <ion-item margin-top>
    <ion-label stacked>Form Label</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea type="text" rows="6" [(ngModel)]="variable"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

**Is it possible to disable automatic form-validation in Ionic 3?**

*Note: If I remove `[(ngModel)]="variable"`, the validation will be left out.*

Comment: Could you be so kind and comment first before down voting my question? If it is trivial, than post an answer, please.

Comment: Maybe **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360804/how-to-remove-default-color-in-input-type/41360945#41360945)** could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change rather add inside `src/theme/variables.scss` the following lines of code:

```
// Ionic variables override
$text-input-ios-show-focus-highlight: false;
$text-input-md-show-focus-highlight: false;
$text-input-wp-show-focus-highlight: false;
```

There will be one disadvantage. While removing the focus highlight, you will lose all kind of highlights.

*Note: Original answer by [sebaferreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915438/sebaferreras): [How to remove default color in input type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360804/how-to-remove-default-color-in-input-type/41360945#41360945)*

Comment: You're right; if you want to remove only the highlight when focusing on that field you'd need to use part of the style rules from that answer to target only the `.input-has-focus` class.